# AngularJS not showing my ng-view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to do a simple angular app with rails. For some reason my `<div ng-view></div>` html tag shows as `<!-- ngView:  -->` when I view the inspector. I'm not getting any errors in the console. I'm new to Angularjs and I can't figure out why this is happening. Below is my code, hopefully I've included everything to give you an idea. I'm using 'angular-rails-templates' gem which allows me to add my html templates within Angular's template cache.

`application.html.haml`

```
!!! 5
%html{'ng-app'=>'AD'}
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "screen", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = javascript_include_tag "application", "angular/discussions_app", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
  %body
   .col-sm-12
     :plain
       <div ng-view></div>
```

`app.js.coffee`

```
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./controllers
#= require_tree ./directives
#= require_tree ./filters
#= require_tree ./services

# Creates new Angular module called 'AD'
@AD = angular.module('AD', ['ngRoute', 'templates'])

# Sets up routing
@AD.config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
    .when('/discussion', { templateUrl: 'angular/templates/discussions/index.html', controller: 'DiscussionsIndexCtrl' } )
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/discussions' })
])
```

`indexCtrl.js.coffee`

```
@AD.controller 'DiscussionsIndexCtrl', ($scope) ->
   console.log 'hello'
```

`index.html`

```
<h1 class="text-center">Hello World</h1>
```

**Edit 1**

I have a rails route which is `http://localhost:3000/user/:slug/` and I'd like to use Angular.js on this page with my discussions route so it will end up being `http://localhost:3000/user/:slug/#/discussions`. What is the correct way of setting up the Angular.js route? It would be good be to store the `:slug` in my Angular's discussions controller.

Comment: what URL are you navigating to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work for the `discussion` route.

Two things I would check:

1. Your `otherwise` route has a `redirectTo: /discussion`**`s`**. This is a blank route, as the only other route you define is `/discussion` (no s). If you are not navigating to `discussion` then you will get an empty view.
2. Double check the javascript code that is generated by your template gem is populating the templateCache for `'angular/templates/discussions/index.html'`. I have used something similar which would include the `.haml` extension. Also confirm that you are loading the templates javascript before the angular app.
3. If both of the above are correct, can you verify that you're seeing `"hello"` printed to the console?

**Response to EDIT 1**

It is important to remember that angular is a single page application (SPA) framework. It deals with **one** html page. As such, it would be better if the example url of `http://localhost:3000/user/:slug/` serves the exact same page (e.g. `application.html`) as `http://localhost:3000/` and `http://localhost:3000/anything/else/:id`, and that your angular router does the rest.

To do this, I would turn html 5 mode on in the location provider by adding this into your `.config()` block:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

This will mean that your URLs don't use the `#` anymore, and so `/#/discussions` would become `/discussions`. This will work immediately, but you will notice that if you refresh the page your server will respond with a 404. To fix this you need to make any non-api routes return the same `application.html` page (NOT a redirect to `/` though, just return the page). Angular automagically looks at the path and works out the route it should be displaying.

Then, in your routeprovider config, you could specify:

```
.when('/user/:slug/discussions', 
  { 
    templateUrl: 'angular/templates/discussions/index.html', 
    controller: 'DiscussionsIndexCtrl' 
  } 
)
```

And you can use [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24routeParams) in your controllers to access the relevant information.

Snippet from the docs:

> ```
> // URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
> // Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
> //
> // Then
> $routeParams ==> {chapterId:1, sectionId:2, search:'moby'}
> ```

**P.S** When I first made this transition, I had API routes mixed in with normal routes, so whilst `/users` would return JSON, `/login` would return an html page. I found it **MUCH** more clear to put all API routes together under `/api`, so `/users` became `/api/users`. This then makes the task of returning `application.html` trivial without breaking your API: if it doesn't start with `/api` then return `application.html`.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks, option 1 did the trick...sometimes its the small things. Thank you for pointing it out. Just for the record I had already done 2 and I wasn't seeing `hello` in the console. Can you help me with my `Edit 1`?

Comment: Accept/upvote my answer if it helped :). I will attempt a reply now to your edit..

Comment: p.s. you couldn't see hello because of issue 1: you were hitting the wrong route, so neither the template nor the controller was being used.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! the `api` routes is good tip. The thing is I only want to use Angularjs on this page so I can develop a discussions component not the whole page will be using Angularjs only the discussions component. So when a user lands on this page `http://localhost:3000/user/:slug/` the component will load via Angularjs. Surely if I serve `application.html` only for this page it will break the other pages within the website as these use the rails way or maybe I've not quite understood what your trying to say? Maybe Angularjs isn't what I'm looking for?

Comment: If I understand you correctly and you only want to use angular for discussions, then you are right, you don't need to use the routeprovider as I detailed. Instead would have to access the value of `:slug` using a regular expression and `$location`.